# FB.logout() does not logout facebook user

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api

I have implemented Login with Facebook successfully and now trying to implement logout option.

Included script https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js

Invoked JavaScript `FB.logout();` as per https://developers.facebook.com/

But I see Facebook session still active and user is not requested for Facebook userid and password on hitting "Login with Facebook" or on Facebook website.

How to test FB.logout() is working or not. From the above behavior `FB.logout()` is not working.

Comment: Could you show some of the code that isn't working?

Comment: This is so weird... Wen I logout with Facebook SDK, the login status keeps returning me `unknown` instead of `not_connected`. This is so annoying. 
The answer posted below `FB.Auth.setAuthResponse(null, 'unknown');` didn't work for me because `Auth` doesn't exist in my FB object. Maybe because of the SDK version...

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in Facebook's javascript-sdk [ [Bug Link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/406554842852890/) ]

It explains that if your have checked the [`Block third-party cookies and site data`](http://screenshots.en.sftcdn.net/blog/en/2013/02/block-third-party-cookies-chrome1.png), the sdk will not be able to log the user out since the cookies remain in your browser. It says,

> When you call FB.logout we check that Facebook cookies are set for
>   Facebook.com and delete them if they are. However, when third-party
>   cookies are disabled we're not able to check that the cookies exist
>   and we can't delete them.

So as a workaround you can use the below code,

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
  FB.Auth.setAuthResponse(null, 'unknown');
  ...
});
```

Comment: In Facebook SDK 2.5, I don't have `Auth` object inside my `FB` object.
Which Facebook SDK version do you use @Lucky ?